# Can't get transparent glass in Eevee

Tags: materials, light, transparency, scene, world

So I am trying to make a glassy transparent cup according to a tutorial but I seem to have misclicked something and now every default material when I change the viewport into preview material is the default forest one that comes with BLENDER 2.90. However, when I render the object with the camera it shows the way I want it.

I have tried removing the material from the cup or the liquid and adding a new one with the default white color. when I turn the Transparency to 1 and Roughness to 0 it becomes the forest HDRI again.

This is what I mean
[image]

blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/154d7b8156aa42bbb0c41dcb332a32ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preview and render use different render engines, that's why it looks different.
Just enable refraction in Eevee and both will look right.

1. Properties > Material > Viewport Display
2. Check *Screen space refraction*
3. Specify Refraction depth (glass thickness)

More thorough answer: [My glass material isn't transparent in Eevee](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/162934/78972)

[image]

Comment: I am using Cycles render. I think its something wrong with the Scene world rather than the refraction.

Comment: Right :). But your viewport preview (the third icon) *always* uses Eevee. I don't think there's anything wrong with your scene, but you can [share the .blend](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) just to be sure.

Comment: I have tried your method but all I get is a lighter version of the forest material.

https://imgur.com/5GH6y5Q

Comment: @Goop Yeah, you also need to enable refraction in Eevee render settings :). Follow the linked answer.

Comment: I did in both but it still looks off and is not working properly even though initially it did b4 adding the liquid and changing something.

https://imgur.com/MwGKyWJ

Comment: I could not upload it on blend exchange so I did it on this other website. Id appreciate the help. My problem is when I put the viewport into render either it shows the same forest material reflection or the whole world is bright white when I tick the Scene world box.

https://pasteall.org/blend/154d7b8156aa42bbb0c41dcb332a32ab

Comment: Hello :). First, your *Refraction depth* is 2 meters. It should be around 0,002 meters, or 0 (to disable it). Second, you table is hidden in viewport, so you're looking straight through the glass into your forest background :).

Comment: Ok I managed to get it working somehow after a whole day of throwing my head into the wall. One last thing. How do I get rid of the forest background so it does not always reflect through the render shading viewport. I want it to go back to being whatever the grey default background it is.

If I tick the scene world and change the white color background then the whole world becomes that color even the objects. I want it to be the way it'd be on a fresh project.

Comment: Hello :). Just check Scene world in the Viewport shading menu , as suggested in the other answer. Related: [Why does Blender show trees in my glass cube?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/183705/78972)

Answer (score 0):

This may be the reflect on this very shiny material (roughness = 0) of the HDRMI provided by Preview shading. If you tick Scene world in shading menu, or switch to Rendered shading it should disappear.

Comment: Changing to Rendered shading does not make it disappear. However, ticking the Scene world does make it look transparent but the whole 3d viewport world is bright white as opposed to the default grey. https://imgur.com/GxagJGy

Comment: In Rendered shading, you also have to tick Scene world in shading menu.
You may have change world color in World properties for a lighter color.

Comment: Does not seem to work as when I change the world color it changes the objects color to reflect that as well. like everything goes grey.

I did tick the box in rendered shading and it still just makes that viewport full on bright white too.