# How do I get my water to be transparent?

Tags: rendering, materials, transparency

I have turned up the transmission on my material settings and checked the subsurface translucency, but it's[image] showing up shiny, not transparent. Why is that? Could someone help? I am in Cycles by the way.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. A screenshot of your shader nodes would help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81851/does-transparency-work-in-eeveehttps://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162934/my-glass-material-isnt-transparent-in-eevee https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183705/why-does-blender-show-trees-in-my-glass-cube/